# Inserting Powers and Fractions When Inserting Text

Tags: google-apps-script, formula, google-docs

I made a script that opens a sidebar that can enter symbols and math formulas when I click a button. However, I want it to be able to add powers without ^s and fractions with number over number instead of side by side. Is there a way to do this? Here's an example of a fraction:

```
function insertPyramidVolumeFormula() {
    DocumentApp.getUi() 
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

  // Define a custom paragraph style.
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] =
    DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT;
  //style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Asap';
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.COLOR] = '#91fb5e';
  // Append a plain paragraph.
  var par = body.appendParagraph('bh/3');
  // Apply the custom style.
  par.setAttributes(style);
}
```

By the way, I know the color doesn't work. It doesn't need to. Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do replicate the functionality of the Google Docs Equation Editor in apps script.

Comment: Surely there's a way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Docs Equation Editor:

[image]

- [Use Equations in a Document](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160749?hl=en&authuser=0)

Comment: I know how to do that. I want to be able to do this with Script Editor...